# Obtener Date Modified de carpeta en Explorer Files

Tags: c#

Estoy yendo a una carpeta en especial y leyendo su contenido, necesito que el `if` solo permita pasar a los `.zip` (ya lo hace)
en el segundo if necesito que pase solo los `zip` que fueron creados el dia actual como aparece en el explorador de archivos
columna `"Date Modified"`, como puedo lograr eso, actualmente lo que hace es saltarse el segundo `if`

```
foreach (string item in Files)
         {
             if (Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileName(item)) == ".zip")
             {
                 if (File.GetCreationTime(item) == DateTime.Now)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("entre");
                 }

             }
         }
```

El resultado de item es el siguiente:

```
\\XX.XX.X.XXX\XXXXX\XXXX\XX\XX\XXXXXXX\XXXXX 00000000000.zip
```

Comment: File.GetLastWriteTime obtiene la ultima modificacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta primero obteniendo la fecha antes del segundo if...
No estoy seguro que funcione copiando y pegando ya que solo lo modifique en Notepad.

```
foreach (string item in Files)
     {
         if (Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileName(item)) == ".zip")
         {
               DateTime filecreate = File.GetCreationTime(item) 
             if (filecreate  == DateTime.Now)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("entre");
             }

         }
     }
```

Comentas si te funciona...